# Is it good idea to provide a short video (around 1 to 3 min) via HLS?

Tags: video-streaming, avplayer, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

Is it a good idea to provide via Internet a short video (around 1 to 3 min) via **HLS** (with different bitrate) or is it better to provide the video as a single mp4 file ? From with duration we must consider to use HLS ? I use android exoplayer to read the video on Android and AVPlayer on Ios

Answer (score 2):

There is little benefit to using HLS for this application.

HLS is a hack for making live streams work on traditional file/blob-based CDNs.  Using it for non-live content that doesn't require adaptive bitrate simply creates overhead for you, overhead on the distribution, and is less compatible with players than regular HTTP progressive.

If your video *does* require adaptive bitrate, then you will need HLS or DASH.  Alternatively, simply put a bitrate selector on your player and let the user choose... this is a UX tradeoff for simplicity, and will work without HLS or DASH.